# How to get rid of duplicate old react in other library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am using material-ui in my React project, but I am getting this Error

> Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body
> of a function component. This could happen for one of the following
> reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

Here is My code

Header.js

```
import React from 'react';
import "./Header.css"
import PersonIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Person';

function Header() {
  return (
    <div className='header'>
      <h2>Header</h2>
      <PersonIcon fontsize="large" className="header_icon"/>    
    </div>
  )
}

export default Header
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Header from './Header';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="app">

      <Header />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: If this is all that you have on your project, you probably have diferrent version of `react` and `react-dom`. If not, please, provide us more info about it.

Comment: Nope, I-ve checked my package.json , versions are same, problem is in material-ui, it uses old react version, how can I fix that?

Comment: Wich version of react and material-ui are you using?

Comment: "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  }

Comment: Material-ui `4.11` has a peerDependency on `react: ^16.8.0` and you have `react: 17.0.1`. Try downgrad your react version to `react: 16.x.x`.

Comment: It solved the problem, post it as answer and I'll mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Material-ui 4.11 has a peerDependency on react: ^16.8.0 and you have react: 17.0.1. Try downgrad your react version to react: 16.x.x